# Disable built in hash from cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks

Oke, so I have been messing around for 5 hours straight right now and I finally managed to get my own hashed password into the post data of cakephp ( 2.x ). It has come to my attention that the login() function also hashes the password. If not, then there is something else wrong and I'm not sure what.

I hashed the password which an user filled in and it is equally to the one in my database. However, when I use $this->Auth->login() it fails to login. It keeps returning false. When it returns false, I'm checking what the current data is ( $this->request->data['account']['password'] and this does equal to my password in the database.

Is there any ( simple ) way to remove the has from cakephp so I can use my own?

The code of which I am talking about is as following;

```
public function index() {
    if($this->Session->check('Auth.User')){
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Authentication', 'action' => 'test'));      
    }

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $password = $this->request->data['account']['username'];
        $this->hashPasswords($this->request->data);
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Welcome, '. $this->Auth->user('username')));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password; '. $this->request->data['account']['username'] ."--". $this->request->data['account']['password'] ));
            $this->request->data['account']['password'] = $password;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly! And then read **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords** and **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-password-hasher-classes**

Comment: It's cakephp 2.5.1 ^_^

Comment: Decided to avoid the built in authentication and create my own. :)